# How to modify a lower file through an OverlayFS directory?

Tags: overlayfs

I want Linux's [OverlayFS](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/overlayfs.txt) to behave like [AUFS](http://aufs.sourceforge.net/) when writing to a lower file.  I want it to *write through* to the lower directory.  For example, suppose I have two files named `L/lower` and `U/upper`.

```
mount -t overlay -o lowerdir=L,upperdir=U,workdir=W overlay X
```

This would merge `L` and `U` into a single OverlayFS directory named `X`.  So now the two files would be accessible as `X/lower` and `X/upper`.

Therefore I could modify the lower file through the OverlayFS directory.  For example:

```
echo 'This is a modification' >> X/lower
```

But this is where it misbehaves on me.  It does not actually modify the lower file `L/lower`.  Instead it creates a new upper file called `U/lower` and writes my modification there.  This is not what I want.  I want `X` to serve as a convenient, single access point for editing purposes.

How can I make the modification to `X/lower` write through to `L/lower`?

Comment: lower is readonly. thats how it works. you can recursively mount overlay over overlays, though.

Comment: I've posted a couple of answers to my own question (https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/393930) which covers this topic.

Comment: Is switching the role of upper and lower an option?  Or do you need to write to both upper and lower?  In that case, mergerFS might be more appropriate.  MergerFS cannot do COW, though.

Comment: @MAV, What I wanted at the time is write access to the files in both `L` and `U`, via `X` — ‘a convenient, single access point for editing purposes’ — what AUFS gave me.

Answer (score 2):

You can write to the underlying directory by not using the created overlay to access the file (the directory "X" in this case). Do it with:

```
echo 'This is a modification' >> L/lower
```

Comment: That wouldn’t be done *through* the overlay, however, which is what I ask about. I’d like `X/lower` to be a single point of access for editing purposes regardless of whether the file actually sits in `L/` or in `U/`; so apparently merging the two directories while actually keeping them apart.

Comment: This answer is wrong assuming you did not unmount the overlay first.  That is even explicitly and [officially documented](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/overlayfs.txt): "Changes to the underlying filesystems while part of a mounted overlay filesystem are not allowed.  If the underlying filesystem is changed,
the behavior of the overlay is undefined, though it will not result in a crash or deadlock."